# Parse SDK saveAll promise chaining

Tags: javascript, arrays, parse-platform, promise

Advice from a Parse developer forum said to *"limit saveAll to 75 objects unless one wants saveAll to make its own batches"* which by default are 20 objects. And to put this in a promise chain.

***I need to do a saveAll promise chain where I don't know how many promises I need.***

**How would this be done?**

I have an Array of Arrays. The sub arrays are all length 75. I need all the indexes of the master array to be saveAll in a Promise each.

```
            var savePromises = [];  // this will collect save promises 

            while((partition=partitionedArray.pop()) != null){  
                savePromises.push(Parse.Object.saveAll(partition, {
                    success: function(objs) {
                        // objects have been saved...


                    },
                    error: function(error) { 
                         // an error occurred...
                         status.error("something failed");
                    }
                }));
            }

            return Parse.Promise.when(savePromises);
    }).then(function() {

        // Set the job's success status
        status.success("successful everything");
```

Comment: I've been having this kind trouble for a long time, and recently started on a library to sort it out once and for all - [spex](https://github.com/vitaly-t/spex). Particularly batches are supported as well.

Answer (score 1):

A nice way to do this is to build the chain of promises recursively.  If you've already batched the objects that need saving into batches, then some of the work is done already.

```
// assume batches is [ [ unsaved_object0 ... unsaved_object74 ], [ unsaved_object75 ... unsaved_object149 ], ... ]
function saveBatches(batches) {
    if (batches.length === 0) { return Parse.Promise.as(); }
    var nextBatch = batches[0];
    return Parse.Object.saveAll(nextBatch).then(function() {
        var remainingBatches = batches.slice(1, batches.length);
        return saveBatches(remainingBatches);
    });
}
```

**EDIT** - To call this, just call it and handle the promise it returns...

```
function doAllThoseSaves() {
    var batches = // your code to build unsaved objects
    // don't save them yet, just create (or update) e.g....
    var MyClass = Parse.Object.extend("MyClass")
    var instance = new MyClass();
    // set, etc
    batches = [ [ instance ] ];  // see? not saved
    saveBatches(batches).then(function() {
        // the saves are done
    }, function(error) {
        // handle the error
    });
}
```

**EDIT 2** - At some point, the transactions you want to won't fit under the burst limit of the free tier, and spread out (somehow) won't fit within the timeout limit.

I've struggled with a similar problem.  In my case, it's a rare, admin-facing migration.  Rare enough and invisible to the end user, to have made me lazy about a solid solution.  This is kind of a different question, now, but a few ideas for a solid solution could be:

1. see underscore.js _.throttle(), running from the client, to spread the transactions out over time
2. run your own node server that throttles calls into parse similarly (or the equal) to _.throttle().
3. a parse scheduled job that runs frequently, taking a small bite at a time (my case involves an import file, so I can save it quickly initially, open it in the job, count the number of objects that I've created so far, scan accordingly into the file, and do another batch)
4. my current (extra dumb, but functional) solution: admin user manually requests N small batches, taking care to space those requests ("one mississippi, two mississippi, ...") between button presses
5. heaven forbid - hire another back-end, remembering that we usually get what we pay for, and parse -- even at the free-tier -- is pretty nice.

Comment: I have a while loop that is creating promises, what do you think of it. It is not working as expected though

Comment: also, can you give me an example of how I would call your method from a function? do I still need my `then` statement

Comment: Back at my desk in 30 mins. Will review then.

Comment: Okay I simple did `saveBatches(partitionedArray);` and also tried ` return saveBatches(partitionedArray);` before my `then` statement. This only writes 21 rows in my table. the attempt in my OP writes 189 rows. And before I was using promise chaining I was reaching my free tier limit of 1,780 rows. I need to reach 3000+ and the promise chaining is supposed to be the solution since I can't do one massive saveAll. so I am trying to break it up this way

Comment: I tried to clarify by presenting an example call.  Too many saves will eventually timeout... Probably 3k+ is too much.  You'll need to throttle creation.

Comment: @dahn how will I throttle creation?

Comment: yeah I hit the same limit as from before I tried to use Promises. How can I delay a promise from running?

Comment: Whatever's driving it just needs to do less.

Comment: I need to write 3024 (or more) things, I guess I'll just need a different stack instead of Parse (or do processing client side)

Comment: I feel your pain, brother (or sister).  Edited again with my thoughts.